# Can we set Cloudflare R2 cache-control max-age?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

Can we set the `Cache-Control` HTTP response header for our Cloudflare R2 buckets & objects? I could not find options in the web UI nor the AWS CLI "s3" and "s3api" commands. I'm now convinced Cloudflare looses money if we can use Cache-Control headers to limit the number of requests to their servers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The s3api provides the `--cache-control` option for commands:

- [`copy-object`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html#synopsis)
- [`create-multipart-upload`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/create-multipart-upload.html#synopsis)
- [`put-object`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html#synopsis)

Answer (score -1):

If you use `rclone` you can use the flag `--header-upload` to specify a header. For example:

```bash
rclone copy --header-upload='Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable' app/public/bundle/assets/index-CsRe289b.js r2:static/production/assets/
```

See https://rclone.org/flags/